# Making a Dojo Vertical Slider slide in reverse

Tags: dojo, slider

Dojo's [vertical slider](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/VerticalSlider) begins by sliding from the bottom upwards.

How can I make it slide from the top downwards?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs, you should be able to set the minimum value to your actual maximum value and vice versa. However, this could get confusing from a maintainability viewpoint.

Comment: there is no parameter to set begin from top